# SwiftUI Image-Button without Border

Tags: image, button, swiftui

I'm trying to create a clickable **Image** in **SwiftUI**, after looking through several web pages, I found this code:

```
Button(action: {
            toggleWidth()
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                .cornerRadius(40)
                .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
        }
```

creating the following output:
[Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIFSl.jpg)

Whatever I'm trying to do, I can't seem to get the filling of the button itself away.
What am I missing for the Button just to show the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not 100% sure what you are asking, but maybe you could try this:

```
Button(action: {
    toggleWidth()
}) {
    Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
        .cornerRadius(40)
}.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
```